# Detecting Mouse's position

Tags: java, c

There is a situation that Someone work on A program. And If mouse move or click on A program, Background's running B program can detect It's mouse's movement?, like mouses's position or clicking? B program is java program. If java program is impossible to detecting it, C Language program can do it? I think it is possible if it use system programming or use device driver. I don't know about device driver much.